# Wiping and Drying

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing

1. Is there a *halachic* basis to wipe off one's hands in one's clothes before washing?
2. Where in *halacha* is it stated that one is required to wipe off the handle of the washing cup?

Answer (score 1):

There is a a halachic basis to have dry hands and to have the handle of the washing cup dry before washing. It is the view of the Chazon Ish (see [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/04/23/drying-hands-before-netilas-yadayim/)). The Chazon Ish is [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14336&st=&pgnum=75).

The [Mishnah Berurah O Ch 158 [45]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=80&hilite=) says that one should not dry hands on ones clothes as this causes forgetfulness. It refers there to washing hands after washing, but it seems to me that the same might apply to before washing too.